# What is the distance between the centers of the large two circles in the figure?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles

[image]

> In figure, if the distance between two **small circles** is **84**,
>   what will be the distance between two **large circles**?

Source: [Bangladesh Math Olympiad 2016 Junior Category](https://www.matholympiad.org.bd/)

I can't solve this this problem. But I found that the connected lines between the centers of the 4 circles create a rhombus. The diagonal of the rhombus is 84.

Comment: The _vertical_ diagonal of the rhombus is $84$.

Comment: @TonyK Yes, I know that. But how am I supposed to find the other diagonal of that rhombus?

Comment: If you know that, why didn't you say it?

Comment: I wrote that in my question.

Comment: I give up.${}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

If the large circles each have radius $R$ and the small circles $r$ then:

- the distance between the centres of the small circles is $84=2R-2r$ and half of this is $42=R-r$
- the distance between the centre of a small circle and the centre of a large circle is $R+r$
- the distance between the centres of the large circles is $2R$ and half of this is $R$
- You have right-angled triangles so can get a second equality to solve simultaneously with $42=R-r$

Answer (score 1):

Let the radii of the large and small circles be $R$ and $r$. Then Pythagoras gives
$$(R+r)^2=R^2+(R-r)^2$$
which simplifies to
$$4r=R$$
We are given that $2R=84+2r$. You should now be able to work out what $2R$ must be.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $r$ is the radius of large circle and $s$ of small circle then:$$r^2+(r-s)^2=(r+s)^2$$leading to $r=4s$.